# jQuery putting content of a paragraph in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to do this for replacing a paragraph with a text area with the same content.

```
function edit() {
    var wdith = $("p").css('width')
    $("p:first").replaceWith("<textarea class='edit'>" + $("p:first").text() + "</textarea>")
    $(".edit").css("width", wdith)
}
$("#replace").click(edit);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/z9xCm/)

But it doesn't work correctly. There are spaces before and after the text.
How do I fix it?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but `$("p:first").text()` is equal to `$("p").text()`.

Comment: @pimvdb: And a lot clearer to read.

Comment: Best way to fix it is to just remove all the extra whitespace in the <p> tag - http://jsfiddle.net/z9xCm/16/ Assuming you have some control over that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You script is doing as it says on the tin. You're getting spaces because you have spaces and line breaks within your `<p>` tags.

To remove the text formatting, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/z9xCm/18/

```
function edit() {
    var wdith = $("p").css('width');
    var p = $("p:first");
    var t = p.text().replace("\n", "").replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim();
    p.replaceWith("<textarea class='edit'>" + t + "</textarea>")
    $(".edit").css("width", wdith)
}
$("#replace").click(edit);
```

First, we remove the line breaks, then removed multiple repeated spaces, then trim spaces at the beginning and end of the text.

---

Somewhat off topic, but that can also be rewritten as : http://jsfiddle.net/z9xCm/52/

```
$("#replace").click(function() {
    var p = $("p:first");
    p.replaceWith($("<textarea/>", {
        "class": "edit",
        "text": p.text().replace("\n", "").replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim(),
        "css": { "width": p.css('width') }
    }));
});
```

Here's the same thing, but in a less compact and commented form.

```
$("#replace").click(function() { /* assign anonymous function to click event */

    var p = $("p:first"); /* store reference to <p> element */

    /* get p.text() without the formatting */
    var t = p.text().replace("\n", "").replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim();

    /* create new textarea element with additional attributes */
    var ta = $("<textarea/>", {
        "class": "edit",
        "text": t,
        "css": {
            "width": p.css('width')
        }
    });

    p.replaceWith(ta); /* replace p with ta */
});
```

Note that the [`$("...", {...})` syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for creating new elements with attributes was only [introduced in jquery 1.4](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-1-4-released-the-15-new-features-you-must-know/#more-8590).

Comment: I dont get the second thing. Can u please explain a bit :D

Comment: @kritya See updated answer for a commented version and links to references. Essentially, the `$("..", {...})` syntax allows us to create dom elements on-the-fly with pre-assigned attributes.

Comment: Ha ik :P i just didnt got the replace part :D. Cus i cant still get regex in my bliddy head lol :D

Comment: For the regex bit, `\s` means white space while `{2,}` means 2 or more times. The trailing `g` means match all occurrences of the pattern in the string. So the whole statement (`replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")`) would replace all occurrences of multiple spaces with a single space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `$.trim()` to remove the spaces at the begin and end:

```
$.trim($("p:first").text());
```

Comment: I think the problem is that there are spaces at the start of each line in the `textarea`. This will only remove the spaces at the start of the first line, but not others.

Comment: Then this is a good example why explain exact what he want to do. According the demo and his description, he want to remove the spaces at the begin and end.

Comment: Because reporter did not think through his solution properly!

Comment: @reporter: No, he needs to trim the spaces from each line, too (and the actual solution should be even more general than that). That's clear from the problem demo.

Answer (score 0):

You could trim each line manually: http://jsfiddle.net/z9xCm/14/.

```
function edit() {
    var wdith = $("p").css('width');

    var spl = $("p").text().split("\n");

    spl = spl.map(function(v) {
        return v.trim();
    });

    var txt = spl.join(" ").trim();

    $("p:first").replaceWith("<textarea class='edit'>" + txt + "</textarea>")
    $(".edit").css("width", wdith)
}
$("#replace").click(edit);
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine but Its a bit. Longer than the shawn one :D
Anyways Thanks :D :D

Answer (score 0):

You're paragraph has leading spaces at the start of each line. These are remaining when you convert it to a `textarea`. So remove the spaces from the `<p>` block to fix the issue.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z9xCm/44/)

Also remove line breaks if you don't want them to remain.

[Updated demo without line breaks either](http://jsfiddle.net/z9xCm/49/)

Answer (score -2):

Use the following with a regular expression replacement ([updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/z9xCm/47/)):

```
 function edit() {
   var wdith = $("p").css('width')
   $("p:first").replaceWith("<textarea class='edit'>" + $("p:first").text().replace(/[\n\r](\s*)/g," ").trim() + "</textarea>")
   $(".edit").css("width", width)
 }

 $("#replace").click(edit);
```

Comment: @kritya: -1 for a terribly poor comment. +1 for making me laugh somewhat.

Comment: Boy, you jump the gun a little bit and the hammer of thor comes down on you :P

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the difference except a syntax error on line 4 now. Edit: Oh, you're using a jQuery object to replace with. Not sure if that helps... It doesn't for me.

Comment: @tomalak Terribly poor comment ? Whats poor in it ? :O

Comment: @kritya: "Its the same bro" I don't even know where to start

Comment: There were minor, irrelevant differences, bro.  But my regular expression took a bit more time to build (and it's 5am).  My updated answer should be a viable solution now.  @Tomalak-geretkal, what time zone do you live in to be up at these hours?